# Accuracy of RNN getting stuck after 90%

Tags: machine-learning, python, natural-language, tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras RNN Cell to perform parts of speech tagging. The architecture is as follows(I cannot put the code because of privacy reasons) :

1. An embedding layer of of 40 units of shape (batch_Size, max_sentence_length, 40)
2. tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNNCell(state_size=number_of_tags_in_dataset+20, dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.0, activation='tanh')
3. tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(units=state_size)
4. tf.contrib.layers.dropout(keep_prob=0.6)
5. tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(units=number_of_tags)
6. tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
7. tf.keras.activations.relu()
8. Using tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss() with AdamOptimizer and gradient clipping of 0.5
9. batch_size=32, learn_rate=0.01

The result for ~14 epochs are as follows (due to resource constraint, thats the maximum number of epochs I can run for)

accuracy 0.0172309
 accuracy 0.800888
 accuracy 0.866243
 accuracy 0.893743
 accuracy 0.896006
 accuracy 0.901575
 accuracy 0.899487
 accuracy 0.898529
 accuracy 0.900531
 accuracy 0.902532
 accuracy 0.899051
 accuracy 0.903055
 accuracy 0.901053
 accuracy 0.898703
 accuracy 0.898703

I have noticed this trend where no matter what hyperparameter changes I make, the accuracy is getting stuck around 89-90%. Can you provide some suggestions to boost the accuracy? I am fairly new to Deep Learning so I have been struggling a lot to optimize my model. I have also tried building Bidirectional LSTMs for the same but they are too slow for the resource constraint and the maximum accuracy that I can achieve there is around 92%.

Comment: Why do you say stuck? It looks like it is converging to 90%. Why would you expect to be able to get higher accuracy than that?

Comment: I say so because I have noticed some of my peers getting an accuracy of around 95% on the same dataset, with a similar architecture. So, I feel there are some shortcomings with my model or hyperparameters. I am fairly new to Deep Learning and I have been struggling a lot to optimize my model. I have also tried building Bidirectional LSTMs for the same but they are too slow for the resource constraint.

Comment: 1. don't use batch norm before or after the last layer 2. do you have a good reason to use relu as an output activation?

Comment: At or around which layer can I benefit from batch norm? All my layers have Tanh activation expect the last one. Putting tanh in place of relu at the end, was reducing the accuracy.

Comment: removing batch norm from the very end and trying to place it somewhere before the first fully connected layer, etc. is reducing the accuracy. Also, relu is performing the best(have tried softmax, tanh,etc.). Any other ideas ?